How to "Americanize" LaTeX Code for an EAN British Barcode?
Consider the following code which I have largely taken from Listing2 of  Generating barcodes and QR codes with LaTeX:
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.5,3)
\psbarcode{3-88309-455}{includetext}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1.5,3)
\psbarcode{00700}{includetext}{ean5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

(I added the second "includetext" in order to display the price, as it doesn't otherwise.)
And which now produces the output

Now, I am under the impression that EAN is the adopted standard adopted worldwide (except for the U.S. and Canada). I also surmise that the preceding code is for a British book as the code price begins with a 0.
And furthermore, since I would like to be able to assign a barcode (with suggested price included) on a book to be published in the United States, I would like to modify the above code in order to mimic the excellent answer of @Terry Burton found in    Generating ISBN Barcodes.
His code (with the above ISBN) would be:
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{3-88309-455}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}%

which would produce:

Now, taking the ratio 1.5/3.5 and multiplying it  by 1.3125in, I get 0.5625in. And, in an attempt to reduce the height of the portion of the barcode pertaining to price, I initially start with a height of 0.45in instead of 0.7in.
So, putting it all together (and placing my attempt below the display I am trying to mimic), I run the following with XeLaTex:
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3.5,3)
\psbarcode{3-88309-455}{includetext}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1.5,3)
\psbarcode{00700}{includetext}{ean5}
\end{pspicture}

\vspace*{45pt}

\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{3-88309-455}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}%
\begin{pspicture}(0.5625in,0.45in)
\psbarcode{00700}{includetext}{ean5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

which alas, produces

I am guessing that since the desired height and width are specified in inches, that may not be compatible with ean5. (I thought if I replaced 00700 with 50700 (the 5 to reflect a price in US dollars) that might work. But it doesn't.)
QUESTION: How may I modify the last set of code in order to mimic the desired output? In other words, I would like to adapt Terry Burton's answer to include a price component in the barcode of say, $7.00; and also---does anyone know if there is a generally accepted ratio between the two heights in a barcode with a price component?
Thank you.

Refer to the answers provided previously on this site, which:

Direct you to the BWIPP documentation for ISBN, rather than some random example found of the Internet. The documentation shows a valid example for a ISBN with a correctly scaled, 5-digit USD price add on: https://github.com/bwipp/postscriptbarcode/wiki/ISBN

psbarcode{3-88309-455 50700}{includetext height=0.7}{isbn}


Explain clearly how ISBNs relate to EAN barcodes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78390221/2568535

Addendum added by DDC:
And thus, the code
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\psbarcode{3-88309-455 50700}{includetext height=0.7}{isbn}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

produces


Many thanks, once again, for a very helpful answer, as well as for the supporting documentation. I hope you don't mind, but I added an addendum which displays some brief code incorporating your answer and the resulting output. Please feel free to remove it if you wish.

@DDS I'm always grateful for my answers being extended, thanks. (It saves me needing to go back to flesh things out as I find time.)
